# How to insert multiple values to DB using select2 multiple in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel-7

When I'm trying to insert all selected values into the DB I get [ result in `driver_lisence` column.

Here is my blade

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">

    <label>{{__('driver.driver_licence')}}</label>
    <select name="driver_lisence[]" class="form-control select multiple" id="" multiple="multiple">
        <option {{ old('driver_lisence') == 'A' ? 'selected': '' }}  value="A">A</option>
        <option {{ old('driver_lisence') == 'B' ? 'selected': '' }}  value="B">B</option>
        <option {{ old('driver_lisence') == 'C' ? 'selected': '' }}  value="C">C</option>
        <option {{ old('driver_lisence') == 'D' ? 'selected': '' }}  value="C">D</option>
        <option {{ old('driver_lisence') == 'E' ? 'selected': '' }}  value="E">E</option>
    </select>

    @error('driver_lisence')
        <label id="with_icon-error" class="validation-invalid-label" for="with_icon">
            {{$message}}
        </label>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Here is my Model

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'birthday',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'password',
    'gender',
    'image',
    'pasport_id',
    'fin_code',
    'driver_lisence',
    'status',
    'fcm_token',
    'driver_group_id',
    'app_version',
];

protected $casts = [
    'driver_lisence' => 'array'
];
```

Here is my Controller

```php
public function store(DriverRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    if ($request->file('image'))
    {
        $data['image'] = request('image')->store('',['disk' => 'uploads']);;
    }

    $data['password'] = Hash::make($data['password']);

    Driver::create($data);

    return  redirect(route('admin.driver.index'))->with(_sessionmessage());
}
```

I just want to select all values and insert into `driver_licence` column like array.

Comment: at least improved formatting and grammar

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by my self. problem was in my migration. there im inserted column lenth 1. i deleted it and i works